# handle error catch properly on fetching then?

Tags: javascript

I am just confused what's the proper way to do this, I have fetch code in react like this:

```
  fetch(
    `api_url`,
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      successResponse => {
       ...
      },
      errorResponse => {
       ...
      }
    )
```

or i should use this one below instead? where should i put .catch?

```
  fetch(
    `api_url`,
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
     // put .catch() here?
    .then(
      successResponse => {
       ...
      }
    )
    .catch(errorResponse => {
      ...
     }
    )
```

is there difference between the two? i like the first one, does the two catch error different?

Comment: The `.catch` is being called when the promise rejects. In case of `.json()` function, it returns another promise, so the `.catch` function can be used for that. It will only reject if you get invalid json object. If you had some response code specific handling you'd have to use the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about about the `response.json()` call failing just throw a new error in the first `.then` call.

```
fetch(`api_url`)
.then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) return response.json()
  else throw new Error(`Could not fetch: ${response}`)
})
.then((successResponse) => {
  ...
})
.catch((errorResponse) => {
  console.log(errorResponse)
})
```